# Update COLLECTION in oracle UCM using RIDC service

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, oracle-ucm

i using jdeveloper for created a function for update some atribute COLLECTION in UCM using RIDC service, in this case i want to update xcoverURL which is it's a custom attribute, i require several parameters when call this function (the parameter are : String collection_id, String collection_name, String cover_id, String cover_url), and here is my code

```
   public void updateAlbumCover(String collection_id, String collection_name, String cover_id, String cover_url){
    String didFolder = null;

    try {
    DataBinder binder = this.idcClient.createBinder();
    binder.putLocal("IdcService", "COLLECTION_UPDATE");
    binder.putLocal("dCollectionId", collection_id);
    binder.putLocal("dCollectionName", collection_name);
    binder.putLocal("hasParentCollectionID", "true");
    binder.putLocal("dParentCollectionID", ROOT_FOLDER);
    binder.putLocal("dCollectionOwner", USERNAME);
    binder.putLocal("dSecurityGroup", "public");
    binder.putLocal("xCoverURL", cover_url);
    binder.putLocal("xCoverId", cover_id);    

    ServiceResponse response;
    response = this.idcClient.sendRequest(this.userContext, binder);
    DataBinder dataBinderResp;
    dataBinderResp = response.getResponseAsBinder();
    didFolder =  dataBinderResp.getLocal("dCollectionID").toString();


    } catch (IdcClientException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

i've got the problem when this function was called , i always got error

> 'oracle.stellent.ridc.protocol.ServiceException: Unable to update
>   virtual folder. Unable to open folder.'

Answer (score 0):

In System Audit Information, you can turn on collection*, folder* and system* tracing for more information.

If you try to run this service by calling it in a web browser, does that work?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it is due to incorrect parameter being passed for the folder or the user name which is being used to do the update.

You can actually use the Chrome debugger to know the exact parameters being passed when doing the update from UI. In that debugger go to Network Tab and clear the logs , then submit the update changes from UI . Select the top most request and the bottom pane will show Parameters that were passed.